# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: table_name.column_name

Tags: python, flask

**it has been 2 days since i trying to remove the error i looked everywhere but i couldn't get anything into my mind. anyone on to free me from this error**

```
class Movie_Details(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
        title = db.Column(db.String(20))
        description = db.Column(db.String(5000))
        imbd = db.Column(db.Float)
        quote = db.Column(db.String(250))
        background_url = db.Column(db.String(250))
        poster_url = db.Column(db.String(250))
        runtime = db.Column(db.INTEGER)
        budget = db.Column(db.String)
        revenue = db.Column(db.String)
        genre = db.Column(db.String)
        release_date = db.Column(db.INTEGER)
    
    
    class Top_5_Movie(db.Model):
        __bind_key__ = 'top_5_movie'
        id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    
    
    @app.before_first_request
    def create_tables():
        db.create_all()
```

Comment: Hello @RanjanThapa and welcome to StackOverflow! Please include the error message so we can better assist you.

Comment: when i try to add column in my table it says sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: table_name.column_name.